# How to fix Guru Mediation Errros on ESP32

Tags: c++, counter, interrupt, esp32

I am writing a simple program involving a single timer and counters that get incremented according to this timer in order to simulate time. This works using an ISR that gets called every minute, and I feel that the error is occurring due to changes made in the ISR. When the error is shown on the serial monitor, the ESP32 reboots and the code runs correctly after until the ESP32 is reset. Sometimes the error will occur multiple times consecutively, and sometimes it will be called only once before the code continues to work without error.

Error and Reboot Message:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1). 

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4008c924  PS      : 0x00060735  A0      : 0x8008b896  A1      : 0x3ffbf29c  
A2      : 0x3ffb8314  A3      : 0x3ffb81a4  A4      : 0x00000004  A5      : 0x00060723  
A6      : 0x00060723  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x3ffb81a4  A9      : 0x00000018  
A10     : 0x3ffb81a4  A11     : 0x00000018  A12     : 0x00000004  A13     : 0x00060723  
A14     : 0x007bf418  A15     : 0x003fffff  SAR     : 0x00000020  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4008767d  LEND    : 0x4008768d  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffffc  
Core  1 was running in ISR context:
EPC1    : 0x400dbc4f  EPC2    : 0x00000000  EPC3    : 0x00000000  EPC4    : 0x00000000


Backtrace: 0x4008c921:0x3ffbf29c |<-CORRUPTED


Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x4008cabb  PS      : 0x00060035  A0      : 0x8008b4bf  A1      : 0x3ffbeb3c  
A2      : 0x3ffbf418  A3      : 0xb33fffff  A4      : 0x0000abab  A5      : 0x00060023  
A6      : 0x00060021  A7      : 0x0000cdcd  A8      : 0x0000abab  A9      : 0xffffffff  
A10     : 0x3ffc2e7c  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x3ffc2e78  A13     : 0x00000007  
A14     : 0x007bf418  A15     : 0x003fffff  SAR     : 0x0000001d  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace: 0x4008cab8:0x3ffbeb3c |<-CORRUPTED




ELF file SHA256: 772ab19893e9256e

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1344
load:0x40078000,len:13924
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:3600
entry 0x400805f0
```

I realized that writing more Serial prints in the code caused it throw the error more often which is why I believe the error is between the **portENTER_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);** and **portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);** lines. The interrupt below is set to run every minute and can be broken down into three sections: The first block increments counters for min, ten min, hrs, etc.., the second block is switch cases that will be checked every time the interrupt is called, and the third block consists of print statements to the serial monitor for debugging.

```
void IRAM_ATTR on_min(){
  // Increments counters based on values of smaller value counters 
  portENTER_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);
  mins_counter++;
  if (mins_counter == 10){
    tens_counter++;
    if (on_or_off[8] == 1){
      on_or_off[8] = 0;
    } 
    if (on_or_off[8] == 0){
      on_or_off[8] = 1;
    }
    mins_counter = 0;
  }
  if (tens_counter == 6){
    hour_counter++;
    tens_counter = 0;
  }
  if (hour_counter == 24){
    day_counter++;
    hour_counter = 0;
  }
  if (day_counter == 7){
    mins_counter = 0;
    tens_counter = 0;
    hour_counter = 0;
    day_counter = 0;
  }

  // for loop for checking counters against arrays and changing values
  // will check the mode for all outlets and change on/off and duration values accordingly
  // Needs to be in on_min interrupt because time_cycle values will change too quickly otherwise
 for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      int mode = outlet_mode[i];
      switch(mode){
        case 0:
        break;

        case 1:                                   // Time Cycle Mode (01) (mode 1)
        //Serial.println("Fixing Time Cycle Pin");
        if (outlet_mode[i] == 1){
          if (cyc_cnts[i] == 0){                  // Check to see if the time_cycle has ended for given outlet
              //Serial.println("Time Cycle Counter being set to duration");
              cyc_cnts[i] = duration[i] - 1;            // Assign time cycle duration that is permanently stored in duration array
            if (on_or_off[i] == 0){               // When cyc_cnts[i] == 0, that means the current time cycle has ended,
              //Serial.println("Time Cycle being turned on");
              on_or_off[i] = 1;                  // so the outlet will be turned on or off at this time and a new cycle starts
            }                                     // using the number in the duration array.
            else {
              //Serial.println("Time Cycle being turned off");
              on_or_off[i] = 0;
            }
          }
          else{
            //Serial.println("Time Cycle deincremented");
            cyc_cnts[i] --;                       // Decreases current time cycle by 1 every minute (ISR called every minute)
          }
        }
        break;

        case 2:                                   // Daily Repeat Mode (10) (mode 2)
        if ((tens_counter + 6 * hour_counter) < on_time[i]){
          on_or_off[i] = 0;
        }
        else if ((tens_counter + 6 * hour_counter) < (on_time[i] + duration[i])){
            on_or_off[i] = 1;
        }
        else{
          on_or_off[i] = 0;
        }
        break;

        case 3:                                   // Permanent State Mode (11) (mode 3)  
        break;
      }
  }
  
  portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);
  // Give a semaphore that we can check in the loop
  xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(timerSemaphore, NULL);
  // It is safe to use digitalRead/Write here if you want to toggle an output  
  Serial.println("Current Time: ");
  Serial.print(hour_counter);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(tens_counter);
  Serial.print(mins_counter);
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: Don't call `Serial` functions from an interrupt handler. If you want to crash the ESP32, that's a good way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried running it with the ```Serial``` functions commented out, but I still received the same error. Are there any other things that shouldn't be called in an interrupt handler.

Comment: Any function that doesn't explicitly state that it's safe to call from an interrupt handler shouldn't be called from an interrupt handler - which is almost anything. There are very few things that are safe to call. You should do the least work possible in the interrupt handler; unless you really know what you're doing, just set a flag indicating there's work to do and then do that work in `loop()` or somewhere else but not in the interrupt handler.